# How to apply image alt descriptions from media library?

Tags: images

Consider this hypothetical:

1. I upload photo.jpg to my media library, but DO NOT provide an alt description there.
2. I then use that photo across several different pages of my site.

Ideally I would like a plugin to enable me to add the alt description to photo.jpg in my media library and have that applied to every instance of that image I am already using. Is there any solution like that available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the Dashboard of your WordPress website, go to Media > Library

You will see all of your images there. Select the image which one you want to update, and click "Edit".

The "Edit Media" page will open. Scroll down to the bottom of this page, you will be found few input boxes to provide the Caption, Alternative Text and the Description of your image (like below screenshot).

Please make sure, you have included the alt attribute in your theme.

[image]